# How to retrieve listing price data for specific event using ticketmaster's developer API?

Tags: api, ticketmaster

I made a Ticketmaster developer account and I would like to pull listing price data for specific events. I am able to retrieve this type of listing data for specific events using Stubhub's API, but looking through Ticketmaster's API documentation, I don't see any specific API requests that will return listing data, such as section, row and listing_price.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to retrieve this type of listing data using Ticketmaster's API?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, TicketMaster does offer this functionality through their [availability endpoint](https://developer.ticketmaster.com/products-and-docs/apis/partner/availability/#ticket-availability). However you have to be a TM [nexus partner](https://business.ticketmaster.com/certified-partners/) to use it, and getting approved as a partner depends on what your business/software does and income etc...